# Redis cluster-network latency

Tags: caching, networking, redis

There is a new Redis cluster setup, one team I know in my company is working on, in order to improve the application data caching based out on Redis. The setup is as follows, a Redis cluster with a Redis master and many slaves, say 40-50 (but can grow more when the application is scaled), one Redis instance per one virtual machine. I was told this setup helps the applications deployed in servers on every virtual machines query the data present in the local Redis instance than querying an instance in the network in order to avoid network latency. Periodically, the Redis master is updated only with whatever data are modified or newly created or deleted (data backed by a relational database), say every 5 seconds or so. This will initiate the data sync operation with all the Redis slave instances. The data-consumers (the application deployed on all the virtual machines) of the Redis (slaves) reads updated values to do processing. Is this approach a correct one to the network latency problem faced by the applications in querying from a Redis instance that is within a data center network? Will this setup not create lots of network traffic when Redis master syncing the data with all its slave nodes?

I couldn't find much answers on this from the internet. Your opinions on this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The relevance of this kind of architecture depends a lot about the workload. Here are the important criteria:

- the ratio between the write and read operations. Obviously, the more read operations, the more relevant the architecture. The main benefit IMO, is not necessarily the latency gains, but the scalability, the extra reliability it brings, and the network resource consumption.
- the ratio between the cost of a local Redis access against the cost of a remote Redis access. Do not assume that the only cost of a remote Redis access is the network latency. It is not. On my systems, a local Redis access costs about 50 us (in average, very low workload), while a remote access costs 120 us (in average, very low workload). The network latency is about 60 us. Measure the same kind of figures on your own system/network, with your own data.

Here are a few advices:

- do not use a single Redis master against many slave instances. It will limit the scalability of the system. If you want to scale, you need to build a hierarchy of slaves. For instance, have the master replicates to 8 slaves. Each slave replicates to 8 other slaves locally running on your 64 application servers. If you need to add more nodes, you can tune the replication factor at the master or slave level, or add one more layer in this tree for extreme scalability. It brings you flexibility.
- consider using unix socket between the application and the local slaves, rather than TCP sockets. If it good for both latency and throughput.

Regarding your last questions, you really need to evaluate the average local and remote latencies to decide whether this is worth it. Note that the protocol used by Redis to synchronize master and slaves is close to the normal client server traffic. Every SET commands applied on the master, will be also applied on the slave. The network bandwidth consumption is therefore similar. So in the end, it is really a matter of how many reads and how many writes you expect.